# How do I trigger a scan for a jenkins multibranch pipeline?

Tags: git, jenkins

I have a jenkins job (`A`) that creates and pushes a new git branch with the pattern `releases/major.minor`. I have jenkins multibranch pipeline (`B`) that builds for all branches named `releases/*`. Immediately after `A` completes, I want to trigger `B` on the newly-created branch, but jenkins won't run `B/major.minor` until there's a new scan.

How do I trigger a scan?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can scan multibranch projects with the [`build` step](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/).

```
build(
  job: '/my-multibranch-project-name',
  wait: false,
)
```

You must include `wait: false` or else you'll get the following error:

```
ERROR: Waiting for non-job items is not supported
```

Unfortunately, that means if you want to run the multibranch pipeline on the associated branch, you need to manually check for the existence of the job.

```
def ensureMultibranchJobExists(Map args) {
  def branch = args['branch']?.replaceAll('/', '%252F')
  def rootJob = args['rootJob']

  if (branch == null) {
    throw new NullPointerException('branch is required')
  }
  if (rootJob == null) {
    throw new NullPointerException('rootJob is required')
  }

  // env.JENKINS_URL ends with a slash.
  env.ENSURE_MULTIBRANCH_JOB_EXISTS_URL = "${env.JENKINS_URL}job/$rootJob/job/$branch/"
  print "Ensuring multibranch job exists: ${env.ENSURE_MULTIBRANCH_JOB_EXISTS_URL}"

  def lastHttpStatusCode = null
  for (int i=0; i < 12; i++) {
    lastHttpStatusCode = sh(
      returnStdout: true,
      script: '''
#!/bin/bash
set -euo pipefail

curl \
  --output /dev/null \
  --silent \
  --user devtools:<MY_TOKEN> \
  --write-out '%{http_code}' \
  "${ENSURE_MULTIBRANCH_JOB_EXISTS_URL}" \
;
      '''.trim(),
    )
    if (lastHttpStatusCode == '200') {
      break
    } else {
      print "Last status code: $lastHttpStatusCode"
    }

    sleep(
      time: 10,
      unit: 'SECONDS',
    )
  }

  if (lastHttpStatusCode != '200') {
    error "${env.ENSURE_MULTIBRANCH_JOB_EXISTS_URL} failed. Expected 200 status code, but received: $lastHttpStatusCode"
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't see how to trigger a scan from the build step. Can you be more specific?

Comment: I added an explicit call to `build()`. Does that help?